# OpenCV won't display camera feeds with resolution greater than 640x480

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, resolution

I have a program written in C++ with openCV that takes video feed from two cameras, displays it in separate windows, and writes it to a file.

This program works perfectly when the camera resolution is set to 640x480 (or lower), but as soon as I make it bigger than that (even by a couple of pixels), it refuses to display the video feed. The windows will open, and the program will say that it is running fine (with no errors reported), but the feed does not appear in the windows.

I have tried removing parts of the code to troubleshoot, including setting it up so that only one camera is active. When there is only one camera, I can have whatever resolution I like, regardless of which camera it is. It's only when I try to use two cameras that it fails.

Does anyone have any idea why it is doing this? I'm really stumped and I need this to be working in much higher resolutions that 640x480.

Comment: if both are USB cameras then the USB bus has a bandwidth...displaying two cameras both more than 640x480 and simultaneously may overload the USB bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was the firewire bus in the computer. Changing the second camera to a different port fixed the problem.

Comment: this wasn't working for me - i needed the newest driverupdate!